# React Router path is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to routing the path in my web, but it is not working. I'm looking forward for advice to fix this problem. Thanks for advance.

Code in index.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Route component={Login} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Code in Home.js

```
<div>
   <Header/>
      <div className="main">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/problems" component={ProblemList}/>
          <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" />             
        </Switch>
      </div>
      </div>
   <Footer/>
</div>
```

The path that is not working is "/problems". It is a component which is located in the folder with Dashboard.(The dashboard is working as I press the navbar but ProblemList isn't.)

Comment: Your path in `index.js` for `/dashboard` executes only when it sees `/dashboard` in the url. So, `/problems` won't make `/dashboard` execute. You can fix by replacing `/problems` with `/dashboard/problems` and placing it in top of `/dasboard` in `Home.js`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `href="/"` - try to add after it *to* with the same path, like this to = "/".

Answer (score 1):

The paths are not relative to the parent route, rather they are absolute and hence, you need to specify the child routes like

```
render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
           <Header/>
              <div className="main">
              <div className="container-fluid">
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path={match.path} name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                  <Route path={`${match.path}/problems`} component={ProblemList}/>            
                </Switch>
              </div>
              </div>
           <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and your links then need to be `/dashboard/problems`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem here:

1). Missing "to", "href" property in the Link that will render this Route when clicked.

If this is the case then it may be showing error in console saying "You must specify the "to" property ". If you have already added "to" property then maybe you did not specify "href" property in the same tag.

For example:

```
<YourComponent componentClass={Link} href="/problems" to="/problems">Problem List</YourComponent>
```

If this is not what you are looking for then provide the error that is appearing in the console. Then it will be easier to understand.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

If your link is http://localhost:3000/problems, then in your index.js you should add '/problems'. Then only your app will be able to detect the component to be shown while its in this path.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/problems" component={ProblemList}/>
        <Route component={Login} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```